# End Part of .WAV file is not converted to .MP3 file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

[image]

As you can see the in the above image, the end part of the .wav file is not represented in the mp3 file. Here, I am making use of avcodec_decode_audio4() api to decode each packet, and using lame_encode_buffer() api to encode it in mp3 format. Here, I am seeing this issue for MONO streams( 1.wav -> 1.mp3 ). I just wanted to know why is this occuring, even when I am providing all the .wav file content. I am suspecting there is some caching that is happening, due to which I am unable to get whole data into the mp3 file. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Decode the MP3 back into PCM in WAV using ffmpeg and check that file in Audacity.

Comment: Done, but the whole end part is not retrievable only some part of that is.

Comment: During transcoding from PCM to MP3, did you flush buffers at the end from both the decoder and encoder?

Comment: No, flushing of buffers was not done, for both decoder and encoder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a section of silence at the end of the WAV file then reconvert to mp3